# QStackedWidget connect QActions to custom QGraphicsView of QWidget

Tags: qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qaction, qstackedwidget

I've made a `MainWindow` with a `QStackedWidget` and a `QMenuBar`.
One of my widgets contains a `QGraphicsView` that I promoted to my custom `QGraphicsView` (`DrawingView`).
I'd like to connect the `QActions` from the menuBar to my custom `DrawingView`.

I managed to get the `QActions` that were connected to the widget working, but I don't know how to access the methods from the `DrawingView`.

This is the code I used for the other `QActions`:

```
draw  = qobject_cast<Drawing*>(ui->stackedWidget->widget(1));
connect(ui->actionOpen, &QAction::triggered, draw, &Drawing::openPhoto);
connect(ui->actionSave, &QAction::triggered, draw, &Drawing::saveFile);
connect(ui->actionExit, &QAction::triggered, draw, &Drawing::close);
```

I tried this for the DrawingView, but I know that it just makes a new DrawingView instead of using the one from the Draw ui.

```
drawView = new DrawingView();
connect(ui->actionZoom_In, &QAction::triggered, drawView, &DrawingView::zoomIn);
connect(ui->actionZoom_Out, &QAction::triggered, drawView, &DrawingView::zoomOut);
```

I also tried this, which gave an error on ui->stackedWidget->widget(1)->graphicsView:

```
drawView = qobject_cast<DrawingView*>(ui->stackedWidget->widget(1)->graphicsView); //also tried (ui->stackedWidget->widget(1)->ui->graphicsView)
connect(ui->actionZoom_In, &QAction::triggered, drawView, &DrawingView::zoomIn);
connect(ui->actionZoom_Out, &QAction::triggered, drawView, &DrawingView::zoomOut);
```

Any help on how to connect from the MainWindow or how to access the ui of MainWindow inside 2nd widget.

Comment: Please consider posting the exact error message. Also a [mcve] would be really helpful to assist you further. What is the relation between `Drawing` and  `DrawingView`?

Comment: It may be easier to setup your ui (partially) from C++. It give you better control over how to access your specific classes.

Comment: Or you can try to manage the connects in Qt Designer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn’t your problem simply that graphicsView is a private member of the containing widget?

You could either make it a public member or add a wrapper function:

```
auto draw  = qobject_cast<Drawing*>(ui->stackedWidget->widget(1));
connect(ui->actionZoom_In, &QAction::triggered, draw, &Drawing::zomIn);
```

and in the Drawing class:

```
void Drawing::zoomIn() {
    ui->graphicsView.zoomIn();
}
```

A third option is to

- emit a custom `zoomIn` signal from the MainWindow
- make the main window accessible to Drawing (e.g. passing it to the constructor or creating a global mainWindow singleton)
- and do the connect directly in Drawing

Comment: The first option worked perfect for me. Thank you so much.